# Make a XMLSerialzier method a public class

Tags: c#, xml, class, xml-serialization

I have a three classes that are serialized into XML data via XMLserializer Method. Is there a way to make the method accessible by all of them rather than have three xmlserialize methods in my code.

```
//Here I'm writing to my class with the data that needs to be serialized                  
PERSON r = new PERSON();
Input l = new Search.Input();
INPUTSEARCHNBR ln = new INPUTSEARCHNBR();
ln.number = pnumber;                  
r.query = ln;                
string xml = doSerialization(r);

//Call the xmlserializer method 
private static string doSerialization(PERSON r)
{
    string serializedValue = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(r.GetType());

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(ms, r);

            ms.Position = 0;
            var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
            serializedValue = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }


        serializedVal = serializedValue.Replace("version=\"0\"", string.Empty).Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>", string.Empty).Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>", string.Empty);
    }

    return serializedVal;
}
```

My code repeats this two more time for two different classes, it writes to the class and then calls another xmlserialize method 
because the input of the method is a different class type. 
Is there are a way to make the method public or have as a class or any other way so that I don't have to paste two additional 
xmlserialize method that are exactly the same but the input class is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't do anything that is class specific, you could type `object`:

```
private static string doSerialization(object r)
{
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Like chue x said, you could use an `object` parameter or make the method generic. The generic way wouldn't have any benefits for you at the moment, but you could use it to e.g. just allow specific types.

```
private static string doSerialization<T>(T r)
{
    // ..
}
```

To just allow custom types:

```
private static string doSerialization<T>(T r) where T : YourBaseClass
{
    // ..
}
```